# Python Selenium ID Tags change each time i refresh the page

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am currently trying to automate a data entry process. Every time I refresh the page the ID tags change and make it impossible. I read that I can use CSS selectors or a possible xpath using tags that don't change. It seems that only the ID tags are the problem.

Below is the HTML code for the button. Every time i try and use the CSS selector i got a no such element exception. I think I am doing it wrong. Please help.

```
<button type="button" class="dark button secondary" data-automation-id=
"btn-footer-save" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:saveAndStayPressed"
 data-qbo-bind="visible:shouldShowSaveAndStayButton" style>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  



wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Save')]"))).click()
```

The element gets wrapped in a WebDriverWait until it is interactable, in this case clickable

Comment: I'm getting an error element not interactable?

Comment: just updated my reply.  If that doesn't work we will need to see more of the HTML, or better yet, the URL itself